# Strange displaying for select element (dropdown) in opera rtl (right to left) direction

Tags: html, css, user-interface, opera

I can't believe: opera browser draws very bad dropdown as you see:

My Css:

```
select {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
    outline: none;
    width: 185px;
    color: rgb(3, 28, 97);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Result:

[image]

And when I change direction to ltr:

```
select {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
    outline: none;
    width: 185px;
    color: rgb(3, 28, 97);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;
}
```

Result is:

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: My version of Opera doesn't display it like this - (Mac, v24). It displayed exactly like the FF version of a select. Works perfectly. One solution, however, may be to set appearance: none and create the drop-down yourself.

Comment: Yes I noticed this too. It's seems to be an opera bug. A few months ago chrome updated its default styling for the select element (it used to look like the ltr image you included) and at the same time opera's select button styling broke in rtl